# change colour of shadow behind image in magnfic popup

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, magnific-popup

I am trying to change the opacity and potentially colour of the shadow behind an image in magnific popup. I have tried playing around with the css of the pop up. By changing the #number in background. To no avail. Please help . I am using bootstrap as a framework.
Here is the CSS:

```
/* The shadow behind the image */
.mfp-figure {
  line-height: 0; }
  .mfp-figure:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    background: #444; }
  .mfp-figure small {
    color: #BDBDBD;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px; }
  .mfp-figure figure {
    margin: 0; }
```

Comment: The shadow colour is defined by the `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);` in the `box-shadow` property-value, changing red, green and blue components (the first three `0` values) will, probably, change the colour.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I can't seem to make it work. I just want solid black background and 100% opaque. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By modifying the box-shadow property, you can change or alter the color of this pop up. Simply replace `box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);` with `rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)` and this should do what you are looking to accomplish.